# Get the next LocalDateTime for a given day of week

Tags: java, java-8, jodatime, java-time

I want to create instance of `LocalDateTime` at the date/time of the next (for example) Monday.

Is there any method in Java Time API, or should I make calculations how many days are between current and destination dates and then use LocalDateTime.of() method?

Comment: I would recommend : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: @Fincio Certainly not.

Comment: LocalDateTime plusWeeks(long weeks) ?

Comment: @Fincio Still no :). Read my answer.

Comment: Does the time of day matter for you, too? If yes then the accepted answer might not be exactly what you are looking for otherwise it is a good answer.

Comment: No :) I asked for days and it works perfectly well

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no need to do any calculations by hand.

You can adjust a given date with an adjuster with the method [`LocalDateTime.with(adjuster)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-). There is a built-in adjuster for the next day of the week: [`TemporalAdjusters.next(dayOfWeek)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#next-java.time.DayOfWeek-):

> Returns the next day-of-week adjuster, which adjusts the date to the first occurrence of the specified day-of-week after the date being adjusted.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime nextMonday = dateTime.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
    System.out.println(nextMonday);
}
```

This code will return the next monday based on the current date.

Using static imports, this makes the code easier to read:

```
LocalDateTime nextMonday = dateTime.with(next(MONDAY));
```

---

Do note that if the current date is already on a monday, this code will return the next monday (i.e. the monday from the next week). If you want to keep the current date in that case, you can use [`nextOrSame(dayOfWeek)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#nextOrSame-java.time.DayOfWeek-).

Comment: Tip: Pass a `ZoneId` to `now( ZoneId )` if you want a specific time zone rather than the JVM’s current default time zone.

Comment: The *java.time* classes are built into Java 8 and later, and Android 26 and later. Most *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: And what can I do to set the time?