# How to get a DateTime/Calendar instance with the Time of next Monday 6:00am?

Tags: java, android, datetime, jodatime

How can I get the millisecond value (since Unix Epoch) of a specific time next week. When my code executes, it needs to get next Monday at 6:00 am in milliseconds. I cannot pass in any static values, it has to be dynamic.

For example:

If it's currently `Tue 05/05/2020 21:30` the code must return the millisecond value of `Mon 11/05/2020 06:00`

Or

If it's currently `Mon 04/05/2020 05:59` the code must return the millisecond value of `Mon 04/05/2020 06:00`

I've read alot of the similar questions but none of them give a definitive answer or only focus on the day of the week and do not factor the specific time (in my case 06:00). I've looked into using `TemporalAdjusters` but I'm hesitant to include them in my android project as they require API 26 (my min is 21). I've looked at JodaTime but couldn't find a suitable function to round to a specific time.

In the code below, I attempted to implement some sort of solution but came across issues when the DateTime was on a Monday but after 06:00.

```
Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
date1.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

while (date1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.MONDAY) {
    date1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
while (date1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 6){
    date1.add(Calendar.HOUR,1);
}
```

Comment: You should use LocalDateTime instead of Calendar

Comment: See [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35365671/642706) on the original of this duplicate Question. For Android specifically, be sure to read [my Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35365571/get-the-next-localdatetime-for-a-given-day-of-week#comment108968946_35365671) there.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use either `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDateTime`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: `LocalDate.now(zone).with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)).atTime(LocalTime.of(6, 0)).atZone(zone).toInstant().toEpochMilli()` where `zone` is your time zone, for example `ZoneId.of("Europe/London")`. On my computer just gave 1 589 173 200 000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joda time is great for stuff like this. For example, the millisecond of the current day is `DateTime.now().withTimeAtStartOfDay()`. Which day of the week is `DateTime.now().dayOfWeek()` (Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, etc.). There is a `plusDays()` method to move to the future. Combine these with a switch statement to figure out the number of days to add and you should arrive at the desired solution. Oh, and re-reading your question, it should be straightforward to add the number of milliseconds necessary to get to 6:00 from the start of the day...sorry I missed that ;-) Good luck!

Comment: The [*Joda-Time*](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), having been officially replaced by the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: Interesting thanks for the heads up! I love Joda Time. I hope the replacement is as good.

Comment: [*Joda-Time*](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/), [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) implementation, the back-port [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), and the extended functionality project [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) are all led by the same man, [Stephen Colebourne](https://www.linkedin.com/in/stephencolebourne). All of them are excellent, indeed, industry-leading.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you. (DateUtils: from `commons-lang3` lib)

```
public Date getNextMonday() {
   Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

   while (now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.MONDAY || now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 6) {
      now.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
      now.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
   }

   Date date = now.getTime();
   date = DateUtils.truncate(date, Calendar.DATE);
   date = DateUtils.addHours(date, 6);

   return date;
}
```

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.